# What's the difference between VARNAME_T and VARNAME_P in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm newbie in programming especially c and c++.

I often saw VARNAME_P and VARNAME_T in c/c++. 
What are the difference between those two?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean exactly the letters `VARNAME_P`, or is `VARNAME` a placeholder for any number of other names?  Can you give an example?  An `_t` suffix usually indicates a type, as in `ptrdiff_t`, `size_t`, `time_t`.

Comment: I mean like, size_t, uint32_t

Comment: What, no mention of **case-sensitivity** in any of the answers?  I'm disappointed.

Answer (score 6):

By convention, `_t` is a suffix that means "type", so any type might have this suffix. `_p` usually means "pointer", so it indicates a type that is a pointer to a given type.

Answer (score 4):

They're mostly just convention for names. The language itself defines a few types like `size_t`, which is the type to be used for storing the sizes of things, or `ptrdiff_t` the type for storing the differences between pointers.

The `_p` suffix is most likely a pointer type like:

```
typedef int * INT_P;
```

so you could replace all your:

```
int *xyz = NULL;
```

lines with:

```
INT_P xyz = NULL;
```

I don't ever recall seeing the `_p` suffix in the actual standard so that's just user convention, no different to mine, which is to use `p` and `t` as prefixes:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int age;
} tPerson;
char *pBuff = maloc (sizeof (tPerson));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the type naming convention, where a type or pointer to a type has `_t` or `_p` appended to it respectively? If so, there are no differences. If you think about it, there can't be, considering that these conventions have whatever meaning you decide to attach to them. For example, I may decide that all my variables that deal with length will have `l_` as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like C/C++. These are two different language with probably differing naming conventions.

The suffix `_t` in identifier names is meant to indicate that this identifier is a `typedef`. Usually they alias some of the standard types, in a way that is suitable for the concrete platform your are dealing with.

These names are generally reserved: the C standards define some of them, and the POSIX standard requires all such names to be reserved for future use by extensions of that standard.

Thus it is a bad idea to declare such identifiers in your own code, especially for something that is not a `typedef`.